# Keep recyclerView at bottom when already at bottom and new item is added

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I am creating a chat app. I am attempting to make all new messages appear at the bottom of the chat app when the current lowest item in the list is visible on screen, but not when the user is scrolled up (like most chat apps). As of  right now, I have gotten this to work when there is still unused space on screen, but when the RecyclerView has too many views to fit, it begins placing new messages off screen to the bottom. Here is my method that creates the RecyclerView:

```
private void initRecyclerView() {


    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chatRecyclerView);
    mAdapter = new ChatRecyclerViewAdapter(this, mMessages, mUsernames, mRoomID, mDatabaseReference);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver observer = new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged() {
            super.onChanged();

            if(linearLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition()==(mAdapter.getItemCount()-1)){
                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount()-1);
            }
        }
    };
    mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(observer);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up adding a check to see if the RecyclerView was at bottom and plugging that boolean into the AdapterDataObserver. I also made the mistake of using onChanged method of the observer instead of onItemRangeInserted, which apparently is required to complement notifyItemInserted in the RecyclerViewAdapter.

Here is my working code for a RecyclerView that automatically places new messages at the bottom if the user is at the bottom:

```
 private void initRecyclerView() {
    

    //initializes and sets adapter 
    

    mRecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.chatRecyclerView);
    mAdapter = new ChatRecyclerViewAdapter(this, mMessages, mUsernames, mRoomID, mDatabaseReference);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    //Creates layout manager and makes it feed new RecyclerView views from the bottom


    final LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    //Makes RecyclerView scroll to bottom when notifyItemInserted is called from adapter and RecyclerView is already at bottom

    RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver observer = new RecyclerView.AdapterDataObserver() {
        @Override
        public void onItemRangeInserted(int positionStart, int itemCount) {
            super.onItemRangeInserted(positionStart, itemCount);


            if (isAtBottom) {
                mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount() - 1);
            } 
        }
    };

    //Adds logic to see if RecyclerView is at bottom or not

    mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

            if (!recyclerView.canScrollVertically(1)) {
                isAtBottom = true;
            } else {
                isAtBottom = false;
            }
        }
    });

    //Assigns observer to adapter and LayoutManager to RecyclerView

    mAdapter.registerAdapterDataObserver(observer);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`mRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(mAdapter.getItemCount()-1);` // remove this line.

and use this:

```
mAdapter.notifyItemRangeInserted(mAdapter.getItemCount(), list.size() - 1);
```

Comment: I assumed "list" should be the list of items in my RecyclerView and it's still just entering new items off of the page. Am I missing something?

Comment: you don't want to add new item?

Comment: Each item in the RecyclerView holds a message, and new messages appear at the bottom with  linearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true). However, when there are enough items in the RecyclerView to fill the screen, I want it to automatically scroll up and bringing the RecyclerView to the bottom and keeping the newest messages on screen.